# Imbedding a smooth manifold in Euclidean space - elementary proof for non-compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

The statement that there is an imbedding $$M \to \mathbb{R}^K$$ for some finite $K$ has a rather elementary proof provided that $M$ is compact. I have failed to find a proof of the same statement for $M$ not compact. I am not interested in a specific bound on the dimension of the Euclidean space - I need only to rid myself of the assumption of compactness. Is there a rather elementary proof of this? The argument I know for $M$ compact has $K$ dependent on the dimension of the manifold and the number of elements in a finite subcover; seeing as it is the latter dependency that has to be removed I suspect the proof will quickly get complicated.

Comment: What's an imbedding? Do you mean an embedding or an immersion?

Comment: Imbedding is an embedding.

Comment: The idea is to cut the manifold into compact pieces, embed all of these, and then interpolate between the embeddings. The details are written down somewhere in Bredon's book.

Comment: Found it, and thankfully seems to be within reach. Thanks!